# Spring data mongodb No mapping metadata found for java.lang.String error

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am trying to use spring data mongodb to retrieve a list of collections from the DB. However as soon as my code runs I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.lang.String
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1008)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:957)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:924)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)

I can't seem to find the solution for this anywhere. Any help would be highly appreciated

Here is my java code which is used to retrieve the data:

```
public List<GateAppointment> listGateAppointments() {
    List<GateAppointment> gateAppointments = null;
    try{
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)getMongoTemplate();
        gateAppointments = mongoOperation.findAll(GateAppointment.class,COLLECTION_NAME);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gateAppointments;
}
```

And `public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "gateVisitAppointments";`

The following is a sample of my DB data(Sorry, cant post image directly as I dont have 10 rep):

[Please click to view DB Image](http://i40.tinypic.com/35jihll.jpg)

Following is my GateAppointment class file properties (The rest of the file has all the setters and getters):

```
package com.ig.avs.common.entity.db;

public class GateAppointment {

/**
 * The Class GateAppointment.
 * 
 */
private String gate;
private String gateAppointmentNbr;
private String bol;
private String containerNbr;
private String iso;
private String line;
private String transactionType;
private String truckingCompany;
private String truckId;
private String appoinmentDate;
private String apSlot;
private String slotStartTime;
private String slotEndTime;
private String isMapped;
private String status;
```

Comment: I think this means that one of the variable names is not the same (spelling, upper/lower case, or 'foo.bar' rather than 'bar') as the names of the fields in your mongodb collection

Comment: Hi Trisha. Thanks. I checked the fields once again and I saw that the different documents in the collections had different fields. Once I ensured that all the documents in the collection have the same fields, it worked!

Comment: In my case I had variable which was marked @Dbref, which was just a string.